# Logging in to a website from another website without using a database

Tags: security, http, authentication, single-sign-on

I have two separate webapps running on different machines. They both require a user to be authenticated to access certain parts of the site. I wouldl ike to make it so that a link on site A goes to site B and automatically logs in the user. SSO is not an option. I don't want to configure this in a cross-environment/machine way.

So then I end up with the logontoken mechanism. site A writes a token (together with other information) in the database and passes this token to site B. site B looks up the token, and if valid, uses the additional data to log in that user.

I'm now wonedering if a mechanism exists that accomplishes this but without requiring a database. For example, you could send the username and password in the http request to the website. If we do this by adding query parameters in the url, then even an https environment would be unsecure because the url could be logged at various network points. I was now thinking about doing a https post with the credentials. Am I correct in assuming that the request body (post data) cannot be sniffed in an https connection between two sites?

If this is still unsecure, what can be done to make it secure? Encrypt it using using MD5, and then unencrypt with a key only known by the two sites (both sites are under my control)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [JWT](https://jwt.io), which is a JSON object with signature and optionally encrypted. It is self-sufficient: just share a secret or a public key and you'll be able to pass an identity without using a third-party system.